# Console and Debugger not working while Unit Testing iPhone in XCode

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, xcode, console, debugging

I am building a logic test suite using Xcode 3.1.4. I am able so far to build the test target and see the results inside de *.m test files as compiler errors (if they fail). The problem is that I can't see any information in the Debugger Console and I can't debug since the debugger does not work either.

1.How can I do to see TestCases ouput on the debugger console?

2.Are there any configuration issues regarding Unit Testing and Debugging test cases?

I would be very greateful if anyone could help me.

Thanks!!

Comment: I guess you are using the built-in unit testing, have you tried the unit testing code from Google Mac Toolbox? I am sure it was possible to run and debug the unit tests using GMT just fine (although not in all versions).

Comment: zoul,

Thanks a lot for your response. GMT surely is a good option, but I need to stick with the apple built-in framework. I think that the standard unit testing mechanism should work just fine, I just can't figure out what I'm missing! 

Again, I can unit test but I can't see console info or debugg the tests...

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/wiki/iPhoneUnitTesting). With it, you will be able to step through your code both on simulator and device.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.grokkingcocoa.com/how_to_debug_iphone_unit_te.html worked great for me, once I unchecked the DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH environment variable.